# Insert on duplicate key causing problems in auto increment field

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `foo_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `unique` CHAR(255) NULL ,
  `not_unique` CHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`foo_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique_UNIQUE` (`unique` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is the table.

```
INSERT INTO foo (`unique`,`not_unique`) VALUES ('John','Doe')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `foo_id`=LAST_INSERT_ID(`foo_id`);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

LAST_INSERT_ID here returns 1. That is correct.

```
INSERT INTO foo (`unique`,`not_unique`) VALUES ('John','Doe')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `foo_id`=LAST_INSERT_ID(`foo_id`);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

LAST_INSERT_ID here returns 1. That is correct.

```
INSERT INTO foo (`unique`,`not_unique`) VALUES ('Jane','Doe')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `foo_id`=LAST_INSERT_ID(`foo_id`);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

LAST_INSERT_ID here returns 3. Why? I was hoping it to be 2. If this is a bug, is there  a workaround for it?

Comment: It is 3. So what? You should never rely on surrogate PK value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id was taken at the beginning of the attempted insert, and was discarded on failure.